# how to assign collection of classes to a new viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have this scenario:

I want to make a `ViewModel` with the property that I only want but my issue is with the `Collections`. So here's an example:

Main classes:

```
public class Customer
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
  // remove some code for brevity
}

public class Order
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string ItemName { get; set; }
  public int CustomerId { get; set; }

  public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
  // remove some code for brevity.
}
```

View Models:

```
public class OrderVM
{
  public string ItemName { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerVM
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ICollection<OrderVM> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Then I tried something like this:

```
_customerService.Include(c => c.Orders)
  .Select(x => new CustomerVM
                   {
                     Name = x.Name,
                     Orders = x.Orders.Select(order => new OrderVM { ItemName = order.ItemName }) // but it says cannot convert implicitly from IEnumerable to ICollection
                   }
)
```

In a nutshell, how can I populate `CustomerVM`'s properties? I only want to select that I want. Any thoughts? Really stuck here.

Comment: `..Orders = x.Orders.Select(order => new OrderVM { ItemName = order.ItemName }).ToList()` or change `Orders` to `IEnumerable<OrderVM>`

Comment: So that's it? This whole time was just `.ToList()` lacking? Many thanks. Could you post it in the answer section so that I could mark it the answer. And it would be great if you could provide more explanation for other's reference. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq `.Select()` generates `IEnumerable<T>` but your property is `ICollection<T>`. You can append `.ToList()` to the query to generate `List<T>` which is `ICollection<T>`.

```
customerService.Include(c => c.Orders)
  .Select(x => new CustomerVM
  {
    Name = x.Name,
    Orders = x.Orders
      .Select(order => new OrderVM { ItemName = order.ItemName }).ToList() 
  }
```

Alternatively, if you do not specifically need `Orders` to be `ICollection`, then you could change your property definition to

```
public IEnumerable<OrderVM> Orders { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

just use ToList() to convert IEnumerable to ICollection. Not tested but it should work

```
customerService.Include(c => c.Orders)
.Select(x => new CustomerVM
               {
                 Name = x.Name,
                 Orders = x.Orders.Select(order => new OrderVM { ItemName = order.ItemName }).ToList() 
               }
```